# Add nickname to a message (simple chat)

Tags: php

With a help of another SE member i've created a simple chat where user adds his/her nickname and a message, however the way i have it right now will display message only without the nickname (part of the code where nickname was added is removed). Tried multiple solutions (like adding another echo session to textarea), but nicknames end up all together and separated from the message. Smth like this:

```
message 1
message 2
JohnDave
```

instead of

```
John - message 1

Dave - message 2
```

or any similar variation (nickname below the message...)

Any help is much appreciated.

chatform.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<form method="post" action="postmessage1.php">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <br />
    <label for="output">Chat history</label>
    <br />
    <textarea name="output" cols="100" rows="25" id="output"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['currentChat'])){ echo $_SESSION['currentChat']."\n";}?></textarea>
    <br />
    <label for="nickname" maxlength="16">Nickname</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" />
    <br />
    <label for="message" >Type your message here:</label>
    <br />
    <input name="message" type="text" id="message" size="87" /><input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

postmessage1.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$nickname = isset($_POST['nickname'])?$_POST['nickname']:"";
$message = isset($_POST['message'])?$_POST['message']:"";

if(empty($nickname) || empty($message)){
    // no data return to form
    header("location: chatform.php");
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "messenger");
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (nickname, message) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nickname, $message);
    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();
    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

// Update Session
$_SESSION['nickname'] .= htmlentities($nickname);
$_SESSION['currentChat'] .= htmlentities($message. "\r\n");

// Redirect back to display content
header("Location: chatform.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the chat output is taken from the `currentChat` session value.  And that session value is updated from the `$message` value.  Where do you ever actually add the nickname to the chat output?

Comment: @ David Well i said i tried different things ( and that part of the code was removed). Didn't want to totally embarrass myself :-) ,  I'm total beginner and still trying to figure out how things work.

Comment: There's nothing embarrassing about it, we're all here because we need help from time to time :)  Sometimes it's as simple as another set of eyes to spot a typo.  As a general answer to your question, at first glance it *seems like* you basically want to add the `htmlentities($nickname)` value to the `currentChat` session value.

Comment: Thnx, i was adding session instead of htmlentities to currentChat